# Bind Visibility of a control to the count of items with same property inside an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I am trying to set the Visibility property of a control from an Item inside an ItemControl based on the number of similar items - items with the same property.
I am not using a MVVM pattern, the bindings are done in Code Behind.

**Detailing the subject:**

I have an ItemsControl that gets populated in Code Behind from a CollectionView that has its source from ObservableCollection. The CollectionView has an GroupDrescription based on a property of the class named `displaytip`:

```
var collectionViewA = new CollectionViewSource { Source = PartiGUI }.View;
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("displaytip");
collectionViewA.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
icPartiGroupedA.ItemsSource = collectionViewA;
```

In the XAML code, I have a `HeaderTemplate` so the items in the `CollectionView` are displayed using grouping.
I want to set the `Visibility` property of a control inside the Item Control based of the number of items in the `CollectionView` with the same Group Name.
If the item is the only one in the group I don't want the control to be visibile. If there are more items, I want the control to be visibile in each one of them.
At first, I was thinking about using triggers. I have put a hidden control in Header that binds to the item count of that group. I have used this approach because this is the only place where I can get the ItemCount of the items inside the same group. Then, at the trigger, I have tried to identify the control by name.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icPartiGroupedA">
    <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ElementeGrupateCount" Text="{Binding ItemCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Stackpanel>
             <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
             <StackPanel>
                <Button>TestButton1</Button>
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ElementeGrupateCount, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
              </StackPanel >
           </StackPanel >
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Using this trigger, I receive this error:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ElementeGrupateCount'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'StackPanel' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`

I am having troubles getting this to work and I think that my approach is bad because the control that I want to reference is placed inside the header.

Is there a way to use this exclusively with `Trigger`?
I think a cleaner approach would be to use a converter and to place the filter inside the converter but I can't find a way to pass pass the `CollectionView` or the `ObservableCollection` in the converter.

Comment: You should use `ICollectionView.Filter` to hide the non-relevant items.

Comment: All the items are relevant, they are only grouped. I want a buton to be visible only in the case there are more items in the same group.